# JavaScript clearInterval position

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a count down timer. Here's my code:

```js
var t = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
var startTime = new Date().getTime() + (5 * 1000);

function countDown() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var milisecDistance = startTime - now;
  var min = Math.floor(milisecDistance / (1000 * 60));
  var sec = Math.floor(milisecDistance % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

  //if(milisecDistance<0){                    
  //    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time over！";
  //    clearInterval(t);
  //}
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = min + " : " + sec;
  if (milisecDistance < 0) {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time over！";
    clearInterval(t);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="time">00 : 5</span>
```

It work fine when I put the if statement in the end of the function. But I think it is more reasonable to put the if statement before 
`document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = min + " : " + sec;`

Otherwise, when milisecDistance become negative, it may replace the text with "-1 : -1" before it stop "setInterval".
However, when I do this, it stop at "-1 : -1" and didn't print "Time over!". 
I was confused, can anyone explain this?

edit:
Sorry that my question is not clear. I'm asking when I put the if statement after `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = min + " : " + sec;` it just print "Time over!" after "0 : 0". However, I don't understand why. I think the code should print "-1 : -1" first, then print "Time over!".

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: is this the code that works fine or the code that doesn't work fine? If you DO put the if statement earlier, make sure you stop processing before you overwrite `time` again .... use a `return` right after clearInterval ... otherwise `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = min + " : " + sec;` will still run

Comment: Maybe use an `if` `else` ....

Comment: @Bravo this is the code that work fine. My question is why could I put the if statement after innerHTML and it doesn't print a negative value.

Comment: why post code that works? Post code that doesn't, then ask why

Comment: Because my question is why this works. Code that doesn't work is the comment part.

Answer (score 0):

If atomic accucary isn't required:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("time");
var leadOneZero = n=>(n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;
var writeTime = (min,sec)=>div.innerHTML = leadOneZero(min) + ":" + leadOneZero(sec);
var sec = 5;
var t = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
countDown();

function countDown() {
    var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    writeTime(min, sec % 60);
    sec--;
    if (sec < 0) {
        div.innerHTML = "Time over！";
        clearInterval(t);
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for the simplest solution with minimal changes

```
If (millisecDistance < 0){
    print("Time over")
    clearInterval()
Else
    print(sec)
```